# How to enable wifi sharing when a usb wifi card is plugged in?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, usb, automation

When I stick in a usb wifi dongle, my computer says "usb router detected" and then I can connect to an existing network or create my own and share internet over it. I know I can share internet over wifi with a command line, but how do I detect when the usb device is plugged in? It must have some unique identifier.

I'm using a D-Link DWA-131 usb wifi adapter.

Answer (score 0):

The stick is not a router. It will function as internal WiFi for laptop.
Luckily, you can make it work it like a router:

Easy way: Google search Connectify. Rest should be piece of cake.

Hard way without using any third party stuff:
Take a look at answer by Paktas here: [Tethering on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/251509/tethering-on-windows-7)

Comment: okay, but as I said, I already know I can share internet with command line, but how do I make it happen automatically?

Comment: does the stick show up as mass storage device? They usually have a small mass storage component with drivers..

Comment: It shows up as a network adapter in the corresponding section of hardware management control panel