# using lapotop as hotspot using windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking

I'm using windows 7 with a wireless internet connection and i want to share the internet to mobile devices.for this I set a "**set up a new connection or network** " in **network and sharing centre** in control panel but it's not working.is there any other possible ways to share the network.

Comment: I presume by wireless, you mean the dongle one. Look at this: http://superuser.com/questions/251509/tethering-on-windows-7

Answer (score 1):

There are many wifi hotspot's are available. One of the Popular is

- [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/) - It is available in both free and pro version with lots of features like drag and drop file sharing, auto internet selection etc.
- [mHostspot](http://www.mhotspot.com/) - This is a lightweight wifi hotspot. I personally use this as connectify consumes more CPU on my PC. (But check the compatibility for your adapter).

If you just want to share internet connection between PC's you can use inbuilt ad-hoc network.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried **mHotspot** but when i shared the network my wireless connection becomes unavaliable.

Answer (score 0):

An ad hoc network is a temporary connection between computers and devices used for a specific purpose, such as sharing documents during a meeting or playing multiplayer computer games. You can also temporarily share an Internet connection with other people on your ad hoc network, so those people don’t have to set up their own Internet connections. Ad hoc networks can only be wireless, so you must have a wireless network adapter installed in your computer to set up or join an ad hoc network.

1. Open Network and Sharing Center by clicking the **Start** button, and then clicking **Control Panel**. In the search
   box, type **network**, and then click **Network and Sharing Center**.
2. Click **Set up a new connection or network**.
3. Click **Set up a wireless ad hoc (computer-to-computer) network**, click
   **Next**, and then follow the steps in the wizard.

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/set-computer-to-computer-adhoc-network#1TC=windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

Well I am using Conectify for this problem. Try it.

Hence using normal AdHoc network user cannot connect his mobile to the PC to access internet but using **connectify** user can create a network that a mobile can detect it and user can connect his mobile to the PC to access internet sharing.

Use [this link](http://www.connectify.me/download/) to download lite version.

Comment: Please add a description of what it does/how it would help. Maybe a little blurb taken form the http://www.connectify.me/ website?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Connetify but you could also try: http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/‎