# Wifi Tethering on Windows 7 - no SSL connection

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, ssl, hotspot, tethering

I set up a Wifi Hotspot on a Windows 7 Laptop following the best answer here:
[Tethering on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/251509/tethering-on-windows-7) (cmd)

It works, I get Internet-access with a second device. However, I get the "your connection is not secure" page on every homepage I try to open.

How can I change this?

Thanks in advance
Eric